# Hadoop FileSystem Counters With and Without MapReduce Combiners

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Here are some following data I have from Hadoop counters. The first one is with a combiner that's identical to the reducer (I used a SumReducer), and the second is without a combiner.

```
With combiner:
FILE: number of bytes read           51034
FILE: number of bytes written       364433
HDFS: number of bytes read        58524138
HDFS: number of bytes written        21686

Without combiner:
FILE: number of bytes read         91149874
FILE: number of bytes written     137012351
HDFS: number of bytes read         58524138
HDFS: number of bytes written         21686
```

So when I use a combiner, the output of my MapReduce job is identical to that of when I don't use a combiner. That's because my original combiner is already aggregating all values for a unique key. My combiner is just running the same reducer again and it's not doing anything.

What I don't understand is, if that's the case, why are the FileSystem counters' outputs for bytes read/written so different? With a combiner, the bytes read/written are actually smaller even though there was nothing to combine? I don't understand why that is. Also, why do the values of HDFS bytes read/written not change?

I also looked at the following with the combiner:

```
Combine input records       3255352 
Combine output records         1822
```

How many key-value pairs could be combined using the Combiner? I think I just add these together, but I'm not sure why that is.

Thank you in advance.